# My function to get text between two strings isn't finding the correct words

Tags: c#

I am creating an application that fetches information about a website. I have been trying several approaches on getting the information from the HTML tags. The website is who.is and I am trying to get information about Google (as a test!) Source can be found on view-source:https://who.is/whois/google.com/ < (if using Chrome browser)

Now the problem is that I am trying to get the name of the creator of the website (Mark or something) but I am not receiving the correct result. My code:

```
 //GET name
            string getName = source;
            string nameBegin = "<div class=\"col-md-4 queryResponseBodyKey\">Name</div><div class=\"col-md-8 queryResponseBodyValue\">";
            string nameEnd = "</div>";
            int nameStart = getName.IndexOf(nameBegin) + nameBegin.Length;
            int nameIntEnd = getName.IndexOf(nameEnd, nameStart);
            string creatorName = getName.Substring(nameStart, nameIntEnd - nameStart);
            lb_name.Text = creatorName;
```

(source contains html of page)

This doesn't put out the correct answer though... I think it has something to do with the fact that I use a [\] because of the multiple "" 's...

What am I doing wrong? :(

Comment: What's the output when you run this?

Comment: You should look in to using a actual whois api instead of trying to parse a web page, [here is one I found](http://freedomainapi.com/free-whois-api.html) with quick googling that returns results in JSON. Use a library like  [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to easily parse out the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying the parse the html result manually, use a real html parser like [HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var html = await client.GetStringAsync("https://who.is/whois/google.com/");
    var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(html);
    var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@class='col-md-4 queryResponseBodyKey']");

    var results = nodes.ToDictionary(n=>n.InnerText, n=>n.NextSibling.NextSibling.InnerText);

    //print
    foreach(var kv in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(kv.Key + " => " + kv.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have already tried that, but the website uses the same HTML class name for everything...

Comment: @Kaneke did your test returned `Name => MarkMonitor, Inc.     
 Whois Server => whois.markmonitor.com    
 Referral URL => http://www.markmonitor.com    
 Expires On => 2020-09-14   
 Registered On => 1997-09-15   
 Updated On => 2015-06-12` as in my case

Comment: I need it to be compatible with multiple websites though.

Comment: @Kaneke `I need it to be compatible with multiple websites though` What do you mean? more questions not posted in your question? Explain your problem clearly that makes you thing you can do better job with string operations rather then using a tested html parser....

Comment: Oh sorry, was a bit confused. Thanks for the answer man. I had been really trying to do this for like days and you fixed it in minutes. Thanks a lot man! :)

Comment: @Kaneke You are welcome... Now you know what to do next. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Oh yes, did it. Thanks a lot. I am kind of new to Stackoverflow so thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0):

```
 string getName = "<div class=\"col-md-4 queryResponseBodyKey\">Name</div><div class=\"col-md-8 queryResponseBodyValue\">";
        string nameBegin = "<div class=\"col-md-4 queryResponseBodyKey\">";
        string nameEnd = "</div>";
        int nameStart = getName.IndexOf(nameBegin) + nameBegin.Length;
        int nameIntEnd = getName.IndexOf(nameEnd, nameStart);
        string creatorName = getName.Substring(nameStart, nameIntEnd - nameStart);
        //lb_name.Text = creatorName;

        Console.WriteLine(creatorName);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Is this what you are looking for, to get Name from that div ?